# Placing text in the center of a CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to place a text countdown timer in the center of a CircularProgressIndicator. This is the code for the layout of the body:

```
return new Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 15,
            value: value,
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: Text("Test")
        )
      ],
    ),
    ...
  ],
);
```

Adding the Align() widget changes the layout from this:
[image: Before]

to this:
[image: After]

I've also tried

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text("Test")
)
```

and

```
Center(
  child: Text("Test"),
)
```

instead of the Align() widget, but they all produce the same result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because your `Stack` doesn't have size, in order to fix your issue, wrap your `Stack` inside `SizedBox`, set a height, and `Center` the `Text`.

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      height: 200.0,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 15,
                value: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(child: Text("Test")),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct version of circular progress bar with text inside (2023, Flutter 3.16.0)

[image]

```
  Widget _circularProgressWithText({required int percentage, String? text}) {
    var value = percentage / 100.0;
    var size = 42.0;
    
    text ??= '$percentage%';

    return Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: size,
            height: size,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 3,
              value: value,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(child: Text(text)),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Positioned`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) They are meant to be used with `Stacks`.

As per documentation:

> A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack, and the path from the Positioned widget to its enclosing Stack must contain only StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like RenderObjectWidgets).

Also, don't forget to wrap your `Stack` inside a `Container` or `Center` so as to put constraints to the box.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            child:
                new CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: 10,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 15,
            child: Text(
              bytesDownload!,
              textAlign:
                  TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A [custom circular progress indicator with text](https://dartpad.dev/?id=fc643cf28e978d55c1e4c1fa10524ab6), using custom painting and styled text

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressWithText(8),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircularProgressWithText extends StatelessWidget {
  final double percentage;

  const CircularProgressWithText(this.percentage, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _CircularProgressPainter(percentage),
      child: Container(
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: OutlinedText('${percentage.toInt()}%'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CircularProgressPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double percentage;

  _CircularProgressPainter(this.percentage);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 10
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final radius = min(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paint);

    final progressPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 10
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    double arcAngle = 2 * pi * (percentage / 100);

    canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius), -pi / 2,
        arcAngle, false, progressPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class OutlinedText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const OutlinedText(this.text, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final primaryColor = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5);

    final textStyle = TextStyle(
      shadows: [
        Shadow(
          color: primaryColor,
          blurRadius: 5,
          offset: const Offset(0, 0),
        )
      ],
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    );
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          text,
          style: textStyle.copyWith(
            foreground: Paint()
              ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
              ..color = primaryColor
              ..strokeWidth = 2,
            color: null,
          ),
        ),
        Text(text, style: textStyle),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Wrap it inside a SizedBox()

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJfaL.png